# Trying to keep parent nav active whilst scrolling through sub nav

Tags: javascript, html, css, hover, nav

I have small issue that I'm sure will be very straight forward to figure out just can't get it to work.

I'm working on site and can't seem to get the parent nav to stay highlighted whilst I scroll through the sub menu.

Hover over 'The Event' and then down through sub nav 'Key Facts' Etc you will see what I mean, the parent link goes back to white and I want it to remain #af5030 whilst scrolling down.

Any ideas how I can resolve this?

Thanks,
Jamie

Comment: Can we see the source code?

Answer (score 0):

You're only changing the color of the `a` element when the `a` element is hovered, you need to also change the color of the `a` element when the `li` element is hovered.

*css*

```
a:hover {
    color: blue;
}
li:hover a {
    color: blue;
}
```

*html*

```
<ul>
    <li> // nav item
        <a href="#">link</a>
        <ul> // dropdown content
            <li></li>
            ...
        </ul>
    </li>
    ...
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#globalnav li:hover a{
color: red;
}
```

You are hovering the parent `li` then the `a` needs to take a style based on this.